# How does contract impose only certain parties can spend the linear state?

Tags: corda

Assume a linear state with 3 parties. How does the contract enforce that only the borrower can move the linear state from one lifecycle to another?

So far the method the I'm using is on the responder side I'm doing `require(obligation.borrower == otherFlow.counterparty)` Not sure how one would go about enforcing in the contract as contract doesn't have access to who is initiating the transaction.

`signers == allParticipantsKeys` just enforces everybody signed but not who should/should not be spending the state?

Can a non-participant who thru some means got hold of the state/historical txes be able to spend it somehow?

```
Lender : Party
Borrower : Party
Bank : Party
participants = listOf(Lender, Borrower, Bank)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enforce rules about who proposes a transaction.

However, you **can** enforce that the borrower is a required signer, by writing something like this in the contract:

```
requireThat {
    val linearState = tx.inputsOfType<MyLinearState>().single()
    val allRequiredSigners = tx.commands.flatMap { it.signers }

    "The borrower is a required signer." using 
        allRequiredSigners.contains(linearState.borrower)
}
```

Then you simply need to write the flow so that the borrower will refuse to sign if they are not the proposer of the transaction.